# Anchor Tag Direct Link Needs to Over-Ride

Tags: jquery, css, redirect, hash

http://2012.delineamultimedia.com/#home_contact

I know this is a bit hacky but, I need this link and other anchor tags to do the same. 
When going to this link the title of the page (section) is blocked off because of the fixed navigation is covering the content off...

I'm using the scrollto jQuery plugin and giving it a negative margin-top when it arrives to compensate for the fixed navigation... here is an example of that...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $('ul.nav a').bind('click',function(event){
    var $anchor = $(this);

     $('html, body').stop().animate({
     scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top-139
     }, 1500,'easeOutBounce');

     event.preventDefault();
     });
 });
</script>
```

The problem is this only works when the scrollto function is triggered. So, I've been trying to do the following and I need help to get this to work so that when someone directly links to the hash tag http://2012.delineamultimedia.com/#home_contact or any others for that matter the page knows to move down extra space so that it clears the navigation.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
function checkHash() {
    if (location.hash === "#home_contact") {
        navClick('#home_contact');
    }
    else if (location.hash === "#/index.html") {
        navClick('index.html');
    }
}
window.onhashchange = checkHash;
window.onload = checkHash;
});
</script>
```

The point of this is to activate the navItem when the hash link is clicked on. For some reason this isn't working though, Can anyone help me get this to work? Thanks in advance for your time! I hope this makes sense, hard to explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would piggyback on your existing functionality. Trigger a click event on your nav on page load.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
       switch(location.hash){
             case '#home_contact':
                 $('a.contact-nav').trigger('click');
                 break;
             default:
                 $('#top_logo a').trigger('click');
                 break;
       };     
 });
```

In other words. Clicking on your nav already works, you can just reuse that functionality.

Comment: Well that script isn't throwing an error but, its not working either. http://2012.delineamultimedia.com/#home_contact

Comment: Could I do this?

     `<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
       switch(location.hash){
             case '#home_contact':
                 $('#home_contact').trigger('click').css('margin-top', 139);
                 break;
             default:
                 $('#home_top').trigger('click');
                 break;
       };     
      });
      </script>`

Comment: I didn't intend it as a plug and play, just to be clear. Where did you put it? Also its not the selector for that part of the page, trigger the click on the item in the nav itself.

Comment: I put the code in the footer. This is working great but Its not going to the right spot in the page. I need it .offset... 

I added this to the end of the click. Does this look right? Its not going up the way I was hoping for some reason. 

    $('a.contact-nav').trigger('click').offset().top-139;

Comment: you don't need to add an offset, you already have it working when I click the nav. We are just piggy backing off that.

Comment: Take the offset part out. And put my script last on the page.

Comment: Brilliant, Thank you so much for your help and time! Sorry I'm noob. I do truly appreciate the help though!

Comment: Do you understand what we did?

Comment: Done, Is there a way to do that for every nav item?

Comment: I do see what we did, we checked for the hash -> and triggered a click in the navigation that we already had so the jquery would be triggered. Correct?

Comment: never mind i just googled case and figured out how to create a case per nav item. This is great!